# HTML link cant be clicked

Tags: html, css, svg

I've created a landing page for a new app and for some reason the link to the apple store and google play cannot be clicked.

What am I doing wrong here?

The page [is here](http://minnut.com/)
and the link code is this:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gempe.appminnut" target="_blank">
    <img class="badges" height="40" src="_img/googleplaybadge.svg">
</a>
```

Comment: From a very quick look, it appears like the item is underneath another layer.  However, I could be wrong, as I only had a moment to review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The z-index for your image is -1, which is causing the issue:

```
#imagem {
    [...]
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Change it to 1 or remove it altogether, and it will work.